# Upload name and image from postman in Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to upload image and name from postman in Django. I'm able to store name but when I try to store Image it gives me this error -
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTSjp.png)

This how I'm uploading data-[Posting data from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr7R9.png)

Here is my code-

**Views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def uploadApi(request, id=0):

 if request.method == 'GET':
    image = Images_model.objects.all()
    image_serializer = ImageSerializer(image, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(image_serializer.data, safe=False)

 elif request.method == 'POST':
    image = JSONParser().parse(request, request.FILES)
    image_serializer = ImageSerializer(data=image)

    if image_serializer.is_valid():
        image_serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse("Added Successfully", safe=False)

    return JsonResponse("Failed to Add", safe=False)

 elif request.method == "PUT":
    image = JSONParser().parse(request)
    image_get = Images_model.objects.get(id=image['id'])
    image_serializer = ImageSerializer(image_get, data=image)

    if image_serializer.is_valid():
        image_serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully", safe=False)

    return JsonResponse("Failed to Update", safe=False)

 elif request.method == "DELETE":
    image = Images_model.objects.get(ID=id)
    image.delete()
    return JsonResponse("Deleted Successfully", safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your JSON response is invalid

```
return JsonResponse("Failed to add", safe=False)
```

**will return "Failed to add"** 

What you want is a valid json response

```
return JsonResponse({'message': 'Failed to add'}, safe=False)
```

**This will return:**

```
{"message":"Failed to add"}
```